# How to apply a time offset to a pandas Timestamp Interval?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Is there a way to easily apply a time offset to a pandas Timestamp interval without needing to add this offset to the left and right limits?

I have the following interval:

`interval = pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp("2017-03-06 17:00:00"), pd.Timestamp("2017-03-06 20:00:00"))`

I want to shift the entire interval by 1 hour by simply adding a time delta, or something like that, to the entire range. An alternative is to build the interval again, but considering the time offset:

`shifted_interval = pd.Interval(interval.left + pd.Timedelta('1h'), interval.right + pd.Timedelta('1h'))`

I was thinking of something like this:

`shifted_interval = time_delta + interval`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that `pd.Interval()` is not designed for time data specifically. For most use cases it would be more convenient to use a data structure that can handle all the special time functionality, e.g. a DatetimeIndex:

```py
interval = pd.to_datetime(["2017-03-06 17:00:00", "2017-03-06 20:00:00"])
interval
```

DatetimeIndex(['2017-03-06 17:00:00', '2017-03-06 20:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

```py
interval + pd.Timedelta('1h')
```

DatetimeIndex(['2017-03-06 18:00:00', '2017-03-06 21:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)